# Is the source code presented on view source in browser always accurate/complete?

Tags: javascript, html, http, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem with an specific web page. When I press on a link I got an application error (not http error etc but application level error).
But I had the developer tools and net console open and I saw that no requests are send to the server.
So I double clicked and selected view source and I saw that this error was part of the dynamically generated html but the html page seemed malformed.
It seemed to end like this:

```
<div id="theId"> You can not access page 
</html>
```

The page as a whole seems ok though. When I use either Crome or Firefox I see the same thing.(IE is not an option as I don't have a windows pc available).
The view source does not allow me to "study" the page e.g. expand tags etc.
How can I debug something like this? Could it be for some reason that the browsers do not display the code correctly?

Comment: "not http error etc but application level error". What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @j08691:The `You can not access page` msg I mean

Comment: If it is an application (server) level error, you'd probably look into the application logs I believe.

Comment: @FabricioMatte:I mention that there is no request to server

Comment: Oh I see. But how do you get the error response then? You must have requested the page (when clicking on the link) and part of the response generated such error, or I'm misinterpreting something.

Comment: @FabricioMatte:I originally thought it was some javascript making some check but in the html page I see the error code `You can not acces page` in this strange format

Comment: Yes, I figured that out from your question. Sorry, it is a little hard to comment on the topic without more details (it could be a JS check as you've commented) but my shot is that kind of error is usually part of a server response. Nevertheless, you're asking how to debug it, so my comment is a bit off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"View source" gives the HTML as it was sent by the server. What's generally way more useful is looking at the generated document structure.

In Chrome, you do this by opening developer tools (cmd-alt-i on Mac, ctrl-alt-i on Windows) and then look at the Elements tab (first tab).
In Firefox, you need to look at the "Inspector" tab.

In both Chrome and Firefox, you can right-click on any page element and select "inspect element". This brings up the tab with the document structure, with the selected element revealed. This is easier than hunting down the element you're interested in yourself.

Also, when hovering over an element in the document tree, both browsers highlight the element you're pointing at in the regular viewport.

There are two reasons why the final document structure (or at least, final up to that point in time) can differ from the HTML send by the server:

1. Javascript that modifies the document. For sites who make very heave use of Javascript (and especially the so-called single-page apps), the resulting document structure can be much different from the original HTML source. That just forms the basis for rendering the page. There's a lot done by Javascript afterwards.
2. Malformed HTML. In this case, all browsers try to make the best of what they have before them to generate a valid document structure.

Comment: F12/Right-click and Inspect element/(Ctrl|Cmd)+Shift+C and click element also bring up the Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Crazy: I got the initial key combination wrong, while I use it probably every day, and a gazillion times, mostly. As it turns out, in my Chrome at least, ctrl-shift-i actually opens a new message in gmail with the current url in it!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your title, if your talking javascript yes and no if your talking html, then its a yes to accurate but no to complete.

---

Html can and is in a lot of web applications generated by the server side language, or even by javascript. So depending on what you have requested from the server the HTML could be far from complete.

Also when using things like html generation with languages like ruby or php, it can be very easy to end up generating bad/sucktacular html.

The story is a little different with javascript. By necessity of what it is, all of the source for javascript must be served up in some form in your browser. But do to the fact that things like jquery can be cached *by your browser* which means the code for it might not show when you open the developers console.

Then you have the issue of minifiers and obfuscation, and then obfuscators used on minified obfuscated code! Which can leave a horrible mess.

My guess is that their server generated some bad html which then broke their javascript,(resulting in the javascript not calling the server as you saw on the net log) which was then handled on your side of things with a error message displayed by the javascript that captured the error.

Comment: There is javascript.But could the html end the way I specify in the OP?

Comment: @Cratylus that's why my guess is that they generated bad html which broke the JS, because that is not valid html and will break most browsers. The issue is that browsers will do their absolute best to display as much as they can, even ***if*** the html is broken.

Answer (score 1):

In **Firefox**, using the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), there is a 'View Source' menu with a dropdown option to 'View Generated Source'. This outputs the complete html source as your inspector sees it, after being processed and updated by javascript. A very useful plug-in, and was my mainstay before the advent of Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, "view source" gives you whatever the webserver sent your web browser.  Web browsers are often very forgiving when it comes to rendering syntactically incorrect HTML.  If you're the one that develops this web page, you may want to take a closer look at what it's sending.

Comment: Not presently true due to a long standing bug in many major browsers. HTML Entities can be sent and received clean but the browser's View Source feature may still display random gibberish instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47819832/why-do-html-entities-get-garbled-in-view-source