# Why do HTML Entities get garbled in View Source?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, opera, browser-bugs

I've seen this behavior across several different browsers over the years (Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, at least), but most recently it happens only in Opera and Chrome - I think Firefox fixed it at some point. If I have a page which pushes a fairly sizeable chunk of data (several thousand lines of HTML) to the browser, if I use any HTML Entities in the data, they come through malformed when you view the source code.

For example, I put a "lower right pencil" entity ( ✎ - or `&#x270E;`) throughout the contents of a page in order to label "Edit" links. However, when I load the same page in any browser and click "View Source", I see a random code that often does not match what is actually hard coded into the page HTML. Some examples include:

`&x#x2#x270E;`, `&#x#x270E;`, `&#x270#x270E;`

Examining a Fiddler capture of the actual source code being sent to the browser shows that the browser indeed receives the CORRECT codes. Something seems to go awry as soon as the browser tries to display it in a view-source tab.

It happens with other codes too, `&nbsp;` becomes `&nbnbsp;` or `&nnbsp;` etc. Mysteriously, these randomize with each refresh. Once in a while they come through correct, though most of the time they get garbled. The codes appear to render correctly on the front-end, is this just a bug in every major browser, or should I be concerned about data loss when pushing somewhat large data sets over HTTP?

**Past Tests**

I ran two tests to confirm this:

(1) Spammed a single character into a valid HTML5 page's contents hosted on a public facing AWS LAMP server. Viewed the contents in Opera and viewed source. Most were okay, but about half way down it starts to trip up, and continues sporadically throughout:

`&#x27#x270E;`

(2) Spammed a single character into a valid HTML5 page's contents hosted on an intranet Windows server and served over a NetExtender VPN. Same result as the first test.

`&#x270#x270E;&#x270E;`

**Steps to Reproduce:**

I have tested this on many different systems (Linux - like Ubuntu, Windows 7 and Windows 10 so far) on several different networks. However, I would appreciate if others could confirm this.

1. Create a valid HTML page and paste a single HTML Entity (either decimal or hexidecimal representation) between the body tags.
2. Copy and paste the character to fill up several hundred lines of content (less may be required, but more will be most likely to produce the same issue). For example: `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` ... etc.
3. Save the page on your web server.
4. Load the page in a new Opera window.
5. Right click anywhere in the page and click "Page source"
6. Copy the source code and either manually examine it or just paste it into the W3 Validator at https://validator.w3.org - it will help to point out the incorrectly formatted HTML Entities.

**Opera 49.0 Illustration**

See below how the Code Inspector shows the correct HTML Entity code. However, when you view Page Source for the same section, the code gets malformed.

[image: Opera 49.0 Test - Code Inspector is correct whereas Page source is wrong]

Comment: This is not normal behaviour.

Comment: It's happened for as long as I can recall - honestly I kept expecting a bug fix of some sort for Firefox, but then started noticing it in other browsers too. This is just plain HTML - Noticed it because I run all my stuff through the W3 Validator, which does not like incorrect HTML Entities at all.

Comment: I think you have a mishaving web-proxy between you and the websites you're visiting that's incorrectly reencoding the webpages you're loading. What happens if you use a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark to view the raw network packets? Does this happen to only HTTP sites and not HTTPS or Tor sites?

Comment: @Dai - I have a NetExtender VPN between me and some intranet sites I work on. I thought of that too and tested it on a public facing AWS LAMP server with the same result - just spammed a single character into a valid HTML page's contents and viewed source. Quite a few of them still got muddled.That test was HTTPS. The with-VPN test was HTTP

Comment: @Dai - Ran a Fiddler test on a public-facing HTTP file and the contents comes through the wire completely correct. So the issue seems only to be with browsers' built in View Source features... It just seems so strange that every major browser has shared the same bug for so long and it's never been noticed before.

Comment: @Typel I guarantee this is not a multiple-browser bug but a misconfiguration or issue with your computer. Are you using a non-Latin Windows Codepage? or a non-English edition of Windows? Perhaps your default UI font is corrupted or you have graphics card driver issues.

Comment: @Dai - I added some steps to reproduce - I'd appreciate if you or someone could confirm your assessment that it is not a bug. I've done these tests across multiple systems and networks with the same puzzling results. I'm not using any non-standard character sets, the page is encoded in UTF-8. Furthermore, the code is _only_ ever malformed when using "View source".

Comment: I did another round of testing recently using Firefox and Opera in Windows 7 and also Linux from several different physical locations and the issue seems to have gone away. At least two of the machines were the same machines and network that I had used before, albeit with updated browsers. I had reported this as a browser bug, so I'm guessing it was corrected at some point. Since it had affected several browsers in the past, maybe it was an issue with a shared engine such as webkit.

Comment: Browser bug, reported it to Chromium. [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=940324#c2)